# Typesafe filteration of List of ADTs by a type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, type-safety

Consider the following example:

**I.**

```
class A

class B

sealed trait Test {
  type Meta
}

case class Test1() extends Test {
  type Meta = A
}
case class Test2() extends Test {
  type Meta = B
}

case class Info[T <: Test](t: T, m: T#Meta)

//Filters List[Info[_ <: Test]] by a generic type T <: Test and returns List[Info[T]]
def filter[T <: Test: ClassTag](lst: List[Info[_ <: Test]])(
    implicit ev: ClassTag[T#Meta]): List[Info[T]] =
  lst.collect {
    case Info(t: T, a: T#Meta) =>
      val i: Info[T] = Info[T](t, a)
      i
  }
```

[**SCASTIE DEMO**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UdYugfa4QgepgPETAnWHhg)

The thing that made me stuck is if the `PartialFunction`'s `case` is exhaustive. I tried to fully pattern match the `Info[_ <: Test]` as follows:

**II.**

```
val t: Info[_ <: Test] = ???
t match {
  case Info(t: Test1, a: Test1#Meta) =>
    println("1")
  case Info(t: Test2, a: Test2#Meta) =>
    println("2")
}
```

[**SCASTIE DEMO**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cq8w9NmmTM2qq3MCKSLJ2A)

and got the following (pretty scary) warning:

```
match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), ??), Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), A()), 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), B()), Info(??, (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info(Test1(), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info(Test1(), B()), Info(Test2(), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))),   
Info(Test2(), A())
```

**QUESTION:** Is the `filter` implementation under the case ***I*** correct in terms of semantic or some weird `case`s are missed?

Comment: Also note that in **section I**, the `match` in the `collect` function does not need to be an exhaustive `match`, as unmatched elements will be filtered out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as you can see, you have a list of suggested breaking cases. For example, `Info(Test1(), B())`. Let's construct one of those.

Unlike path dependent types as in `def foo(t: Test)(meta: t.Meta) = ???`, type projections as you use them in `case class Info` don't encode the implication of `T = Test1 => T#Meta = A`. Though I'll need a simple utility method to convince scalac into inferring the type I want.

```scala
def castMeta[T <: Test](t: T#Meta): Test#Meta = t
```

With it, we're able to obtain values typed as Test#Meta from both A and B.

So,

```
val t: Info[_ <: Test] = Info[Test](Test1(), castMeta[Test2](new B))
```

will cause a `MatchError` at runtime, and making it didn't involve any "hacks" like nulls, `asInstanceOf`s or `ClassTag`s.

Note also that general type projections of form `Type#Member` are scheduled for removal in Scala 3 due to soundness issues.

**Edit:** note that your filter will likely do what you want since you're supplying the target pair of types yourself, it's just that your model totally allows weird cases that scalac is warning you about :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to rewrite `case class Info[T <: Test](t: T, m: T#Meta)` using path-dependent type as `case class Info[T <: Test](t: T, m: t.Meta)` and got the error `Implementation restriction: case classes cannot have dependencies between parameters`. Can you imagine any workaround to port such code to Scala 3?

Comment: You can use a plain class with custom unapply, or do something entirely different and use e.g. [match types](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FNUqLEbbTxyw04l0JSOP9A). Though I suggest dropping the runtime matching entirely and using a plain enum with two cases.

Comment: I like your approach with match types. Looks cool.