# "Effective type-safety" by prohibiting some cases with macro

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-macros, type-safety, type-projection

**Problem**:

In one of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939443/typesafe-filteration-of-list-of-adts-by-a-type-parameter) I provided an example with the following pattern-matching

```
class A

class B

sealed trait Test {
  type Meta
}

case class Test1() extends Test {
  type Meta = A
}
case class Test2() extends Test {
  type Meta = B
}

case class Info[T <: Test](t: T, m: T#Meta)

val t: Info[_ <: Test] = ???
t match {
  case Info(t: Test1, a: Test1#Meta) =>
    println("1")
  case Info(t: Test2, a: Test2#Meta) =>
    println("2")
}
```

This code compiles with the following warning:

```
match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), ??), Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), A()), 
Info((x: _$2 forSome x not in (Test1, Test2)), B()), Info(??, (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info(Test1(), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))), 
Info(Test1(), B()), Info(Test2(), (x: _$2#Meta forSome x not in (A, B))),   
Info(Test2(), A())
```

As [Oleg Pyzhcov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758343/oleg-pyzhcov) greatly explined in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940277/8990329) the it is indeed possible to construct a value which would fail to match.

**My solution**:

So the solution I currently think of is to prohibit such object creation with a simple macro. Here it is:

```
object Info {
  def apply[T <: Test](t: T, m: T#Meta): Info[T] = macro applyImpl[T]

  def applyImpl[T <: Test](c: blackbox.Context)(t: c.Expr[T], m: c.Expr[T#Meta]): c.Expr[Info[T]] = {
    import c.universe._


    val sourceType = weakTypeTag[T].tpe
    if (!sourceType.typeSymbol.isClass || !sourceType.typeSymbol.isFinal) {
      c.abort(
        c.enclosingPosition,
        s"Creating is allowed for specific types only"
      )
    }

    //... create an object
  }
}
```

With such `apply` implementation it is not possible to construct such objects anymore.

**QUESTION:** Is it reliable to suppress the warning compiler raises when using such `apply` implementation?